# PHP is working but includes are being commented out (Localhost)

Tags: php, server-side-includes

This is crazy but I bet I'm missing something, marbles probably. My app is working fine on the remote server but not on my localhost.  PHP is working but includes are being commented out.

I hope this isn't a duplicate as the alternative posts suggested when posting don't my question.

Comment: Shows your codes.

Comment: Found it.  My local version of PHP must be old or something.  <?php blah ?> works but <? blah ?> gets commented out.

Comment: What makes you say that your includes "are being commented out"? Do you mean they are not being included? What is your include_path? What happens if you change one of the calls to `include() ` to `require()`?

Comment: Hi Mr Glass,  the code is displayed in the developer tools inspector with html comments <!-- <? blah ?> --> But i think i have the solution.

Answer (score 0):

How I see in the comment you have mentioned that `<? blah ?>` gets commented out. 
In your php.ini  you should change from `short_open_tag=Off` into `short_open_tag=On` then restart the apache

This is one way that can help you.
If there are any other issue then write in the comment

Comment: I have the same issue as you mention. I do my changes and it helps me

Comment: Hi Aram, thank you for your suggestion, I have decided to upgrade to 5.6.36.  I'll make sure when I do I take your advice.

Comment: Thanks, I hope it will help you. In any case let me know

Comment: @Bir do you find a solution?